# Tinymce Textarea Focus Issue In IOS devices

Tags: textarea, tinymce-5

I'm employed on a project using Ruby on Rails. vueJS is being used for mobile devices on that project. I'm having trouble with tinymce not displaying the cursor when it first launches because when I click a button, a modal window opens, therefore I have to reinitialize the component so that it continues to function. However, there is now a problem with the iOS device. It functions on all Android and web devices. but not functioning on iOS devices. Does anyone have these kinds of problems?